# c# Event Creation: Raise vs invoke

Tags: c#, events, invoke, raise

Before C#6, i was using this routine to deal with generating events in a multi threaded program: (i found it somewhere, but can't remember where):

```
 public static object Raise(this MulticastDelegate multicastDelegate, object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object retVal = null;

        MulticastDelegate threadSafeMulticastDelegate = multicastDelegate;
        if (threadSafeMulticastDelegate != null)
        {
            foreach (Delegate d in threadSafeMulticastDelegate.GetInvocationList())
            {
                var synchronizeInvoke = d.Target as ISynchronizeInvoke;
                if ((synchronizeInvoke != null) && synchronizeInvoke.InvokeRequired)
                    retVal = synchronizeInvoke.EndInvoke(synchronizeInvoke.BeginInvoke(d, new[] { sender, e }));
                else
                    retVal = d.DynamicInvoke(sender, e);
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

so all i had to do was Eventname.Raise(...,....)

now with C#6, i know the new was it using something like:
    Eventname?.Invoke(...);

what i am wondering is, should i change all my event creations to Invoke as it works different to the Raise(), or is it the same thing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never have been using that method in the first place. It's way too complicated. Instead, something like this would have been better:

```
public static void Raise(this Delegate handler, object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler.DynamicInvoke(sender, e);
    }
}
```

As for whether you should change your event-raising code, I'd say no. Not unless you've got a lot of time to kill and like going through your entire code base replacing perfectly good code.

What you *should* do is fix your current `Raise()` method. And feel free for any *new* code to write it the new C# 6 way, i.e. `MyEvent?.DynamicInvoke(this, EventArgs.Empty)` (which effectively amounts to the exact same thing as `MyEvent.Raise(this, EventArgs.Empty)` using the above, except without the extra method call).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will change the Raise() code. thanks for the help.